# Fullcalendar gotodate to next event

Tags: php, symfony, events, fullcalendar

I have a calendar where I need to show empty spots for clients to make appointments. If there is no spots this week, I look up for spots next week and so on. 
I use fullcalendar AgendaView, and I would like to know if I can show the first week where there is a spot. I know I have to use gotoDate, but I don´t know where in the code I have to use it and how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this immediately when the calendar opens? You can use the [defaultDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate) setting for that instead of the gotoDateMethod. Otherwise you can use the gotoDate method in response so some user action (e.g clicking a button or something). We don't know how you want to trigger this action.

Comment: I want to do it immediately so defaultDate will work, thanks. How can I find the list of events?

Comment: Depends how you load your events. If you load them from a source your server e.g. a database, then it would be more efficient to use that source data to get the events and work out where the next available slot occurs. If you want to do this when the calendar loads then you certainly have to do it outside of fullCalendar, because fullCalendar doesn't actually load events into it until after it has initialised the grid (and thus processed all the options such as defaultDate). (Once the events have loaded, then you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents to get a list)

Comment: Yes, I load it from the database via EventSources. I will tray, thanks.